# How to test all possible values ​for all variables to get the maximum result for the function

Tags: python, function, combinations

I have three variables called a, b and c, each of these can assume a different value defined in a range. I'd like to create a function that tests every possible variable value and gives me their best combination for the output 'f'.

```
a = list(range(1, 10, 2))
b = list(range(5, 8, 1))
c = list(range(1, 3, 1))

def all_combinations (a, b, c):
    #something
    f = a + (b * a) - (c*(a ^ b))
    return BEST a, b, c for my f
```

it's possible to do it ? what is the best way to do it?

Comment: idk what you mean "best" but this sounds like an optimization problem

Comment: yes I meant just that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product()` to get all the possible combinations of a, b, and c.

Then calculate your formula for each unique combination of `a b c`, keep track of the result, and if the result is better than the previous best, save the current values of `a b c`.

```
import itertools

def all_combinations (alist, blist, clist):
    best_a = 0
    best_b = 0
    best_c = 0
    best_f = 0
    for a,b,c in itertools.product(alist, blist, clist):
        f = a + (b * a) - (c*(a ^ b))
        if f > best_f: # use your own definition of "better"
            best_a = a
            best_b = b
            best_c = c
            best_f = f
    return best_a, best_b, best_c
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you said `I have three variables called a, b and c, each of these can assume a different value defined in a range`. Note that the variables in your code are actually equal to three lists of integers, *not* three integers.

The naive algorithm to test all possible combinations is 3 nested `for` loops. Here I assume that by "best" you mean "maximum value":

```
def all_combinations (list1, list2, list3):
    best_f, best_a, best_b, best_c = None, None, None, None

    for a in list1:
        for b in list2:
            for c in list3:
                f = a + (b * a) - (c*(a ^ b))
                # here you have to define what f being "better" than best_f means:
                if not f or f > best_f:
                    best_f = f
                    best_a = a
                    best_b = b
                    best_c = c
    return best_a, best_b, best_c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure those are the only values you want to test, then the following will work. Otherwise you might want to look into [scipy.optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html).

```
from itertools import product
import numpy as np

parameters = list(product(a, b, c))
results = [my_fun(*x) for x in parameters]
print(parameters[np.argmax(results)])
```

obviously replace `np.argmax` with `np.argmin` if you want to minimize the function